# compare 2 Observable with different structure

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I have 2 observable coming from firebase with angularfire and using rxjs

```js
private boatsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Boat>;
boats: Observable<Boat[]>;

private bookingsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Booking>;
bookings: Observable<Booking[]>;
```

structures are not marching but `bookings` collection documents have `ID'S` containing information about `boat` (so boat `id`)

I want to to filter **boats** and leave only these documents where ids are **not** matching to bookings collection document(s) `ID` value.

How this can be achieved with rxjs?

```js
ngOnInit() {
  // Subscribe to route params and get user's selected date
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.date = Number (params['date']);
    // get bookings where selected date exits
    this.bookingsCollection = this.afs.collection<Booking>('bookings', ref => ref.where('date', '==', this.date));
    this.bookings = this.bookingsCollection.valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
    // Boats Collection
    this.boatsCollection = this.afs.collection<Boat>('boats');
    this.boats = this.boatsCollection.valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });  
 
    combineLatest(this.boats, this.bookings).subscribe(
      ([boats, bookings]) => {
        const bookingIds = bookings.map(booking => booking.boatID);
        const filteredBoats = boats.filter(boat => !(bookingIds.includes(boat.id)));
        console.log(filteredBoats);
      }, 
    ); 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. One way would be get notifications from both the observables simultaneously using RxJS [`combineLatest`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest) function and filter the arrays using Array [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function.

Try the following

```js
ngOnInit() {
  combineLatest(this.boats, this.bookings).subscribe(
    ([boats, bookings]) => {
      const bookingIds = bookings.map(booking => booking.id);
      this.filteredBoats = boats.filter(boat => !(bookingIds.includes(boat.id)));
      console.log(this.filteredBoats);    // <-- correct
    },
    error => { }
  );

  console.log(this.filteredBoats);    // <-- wrong - will print undefined/previous value
}
```

Now the `combineLatest` will emit for each emission of any of it's source observables. Also all the source observables should've emitted at least once.

You could use RxJS [`zip`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/zip) or [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) functions based on your requirement. Although remember `forkJoin` will only emit when all the source observables complete.

#### Update: Async data

The `filteredBoats` is assigned asynchronously. Which means by the time `console.log` is executed outside the subscription, the `filteredBoats` isn't any values yet. The `console.log` should be inside the subscription.

More about async data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921).

Comment: it returns undefined (this.filteredBoats) while calling ngOnInit as I need it when page loaded

Comment: Please make sure you're using the correct properties for IDs. I've used `booking.id` and `boad.id` as a placeholder.

Comment: yes I have edited as needed booking.boatID but I guess I must zip  filteredboats before getting values?

Comment: Where are you printing the values? Please update your code in the question.

Comment: Yes but where are you seeing that `filteredBoats` variable is undefined?

Comment: I have added console log just after ); subscribe ends

Comment: The `filteredBoats` is assigned asynchronously. Which means by the time `console.log` is executed the `filteredBoats` isn't any values yet. The `console.log` should be inside the subscription. I've updated the answer.

Comment: thank you, before your suggestion I have edited code and also edited my question to get you know complete code. it is showing me results yes, but not filtered, I am getting all my available boats.

Comment: okay I have solved that also, there was a very small detail related to this this.bookings = this.bookingsCollection.valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }); was missing idfield id parameter. now it works well and I will mark your answer as correct because it is complete for my questioin. thanks